Prove the inequality $\frac{a}{b^2+1}+\frac{b}{c^2+1}+\frac{c}{a^2+1}\geq\frac{3}{4}(a+b+c)$
I recently designed an inequality problem which I give below. It's not from a contest, but I designed it to be suitable for e.g. a national maths olympiad. I would be really interested in seeing if there are multiple techniques for solving it.
Prove that the following inequality holds for all non-negative, real $a,b,c$ with the condition that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.
$\frac{a}{b^2+1}+\frac{b}{c^2+1}+\frac{c}{a^2+1}\geq\frac{3}{4}(a+b+c)$
I have managed to solve my own problem using Titu's lemma, also known as the Engel form of the Cauchy-Schwarz. To do this I had to form equivalent fractions and directly show that:
$\frac{a^2}{ab^2+a}+\frac{b^2}{bc^2+b}+\frac{c^2}{ca^2+c}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab^2+bc^2+ca^2+a+b+c}$
To finish the problem, I then had to show that the following inequality held:
$a+b+c\geq3(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2)$
This was possible by multiplying the left hand side by $a^2+b^2+c^2$ and expanding, followed by using the AM-GM inequality three times.
I would be really interested to see if there are alternative methods for solving this. Thank you in advance amazing problem solvers!

That's a common setup, and the Titu step is expected. $\quad$ I would have used the same approach, just normalizing it first which allows us to disregard the condition in the problem.

My bad. I deleted my comment. Can you write down your proof in the post?

Create a new (stronger) inequality based on the OP
The inequality is written as
$$\frac14(a + b + c) \ge \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{ab^2}{b^2 + 1} = \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{ab^2}{b^2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2}. \tag{1}$$
Since (1) is homogeneous, we can discard the constraint $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, and assume $a + b + c = 1$ instead.
Using $b^2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge (b + a + b + c)^2/4 = (1 + b)^2/4$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{16} \ge \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{ab^2}{(1 + b)^2}. \tag{2}$$
(2) is true.
